# How to print till the pattern match including pattern string

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I want to print the line till pattern is matched but including the pattern

for example:

http://google.com/search

I want to use ".com" as match string and just print http://google.com , ignoring rest of the line.

awk or grep would be helpful.

I tried codes from posts but didnt get exactly that i wanted.

request your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep -o` to output only matched string:

```
s='http://google.com/search'

grep -o '.*\.com' <<< "$s"
http://google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following regex: /(.*.com)/

see [this example](http://scriptular.com/#(.*.com)%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%22%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
echo "http://google.com/search" | awk -F/ -vOFS=/ '/\.com/ {$NF="";sub(/\/$/,"");print}'
http://google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Assuming that your goal is to harvesting top-level domains that all end in `.com`, then you can just delete everything at the end, including `.com` and replace it with only `.com`, i.e.

```
echo "http://google.com/search
1
2" | awk '/\.com/{sub(/\.com.*/, ".com", $0) ;print $0}'
```

**output**

```
http://google.com
```

I've included extra lines of input to show that only lines containing `.com` are processed.

If you want to print out all lines of input, remove the initial match to reg-ex, i.e.

```
echo "http://google.com/search
1
2" | awk '{sub(/\.com.*/, ".com", $0) ;print $0}'
```

**output 2**

```
http://google.com
    1
    2
```

IHTH

Comment: Good to know awk solution as well. will save it for future use.